# JavaScript empty field validation does not work

Tags: javascript, validation

So, I have a number textbox and I want to validate it using JavaScript. If the user has not input any number, it will prompt him/her to enter one. My codes below:

```
<input type="number" autofocus id="lol"/>
<input type="button" onClick="validate()" value="Input"/>

<script>
    function validate() {
    var numfield = document.getElementById("lol").value;
    if ( numfield == "") {
    document.write("Missing number!");
}
</script>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: For starters, your braces don't match up.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a } at the end of the script. With that fixed, it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `length` property.

```
if ( numfield.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That would be the `length` property. There is no string `length()` method in Javascript.